# I am trying to set up an automated email list every monday in Google sheets/scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can get the emails to send but:

- Cannot filter IF the email us sent based on status column
- Cannot format the email to be neat just sent as follows:

Dear Paul Get email script working8  Sat May 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100
(BST) Deadlines Doc

- I cannot get the email to send out with the right time zone I am located in gmt timezone, it keeps sending bst time zone.
- I cannot figure out how to make this script run automatically every Monday morning 8 AM

I have combined several code snippets
I have edited my sheet to allow for easy filtereing difining rowData

Example of my sheet:

Col A Dropdown menu selecting Agent (names)

Col B Dropdown menu selecting email addresses

Col C Assignment col = plain text

Col D Dropdown menu with status options (Not Started, In progress, skipped or Done)

Col E To do, plain text to add to the assignment. Idea being to give the agents more detail on action plan required

Col F Due Date, formatted only to date (no timestamp)

Col G= Hyperlink( URL, "Deadline Doc") 
-> Created in an attempt to add + message 4 + ' '; to the code for email formatting purposes.

```
function sendEmailswithDetails() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Email2"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A4:G11");
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
    for (i in data) {
        var rowData = data[i];
        var recipient = rowData[0];
        var emailAddress = rowData[1];
        var message1 = rowData[2];
        var parameter1 = rowData[3]
        var message2 = rowData[4];
        var message3 = rowData[5];
        var message4 = rowData[6]
        var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ' ' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + ' ' + message3 + ' ' + message4 + ' ';
        var subject = 'Your deadlines this week';

        // Check deadlines
        if (Status = ("Not Started"), ("In Progress")){
            // Fetch Status
            var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email2").getRange("B4:B11");
            var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results:

1. Emails only sent if Status = In progress or Not started.
2. Email sends combining message columns 1-4.
3. Email is neatly formatted into separate lines.

Actual results:

1. Email sends to any emails added to the emailAddress column
2. Status column is not impacting whether the email is sent or not

Comment: Firstly, you don't define the variable "Status" or assign it any values, and secondly you use an assignment operator "=" instead of an equality operator "==" (value only) or "===" (value and type).

I presume you wanted to set an OR condition on the IF statement, which would be something like `if (Status === "Not Started" || Status === "In Progress"){` Fixing those issues is the first step.

Comment: Also, if you post further questions, please read the ["How to post a good question" article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You'll most likely reduce the number of down-votes.

Comment: Thank you! You probable noticed I am quite new to this. 
Also, I will read up as suggested. Apologies, had no Idea my question was formatted in a way that is not appreciated.

Comment: No problem! FYI, I didn't give the downvote :) Personally, I think giving downvotes to newcomers should require also leaving a comment but I'm sure the powerusers will disregard my comment as they most likely also see me as a newcomer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I assumed status was column 11 because it was the only unused column in the range.

```
function sendEmailswithDetails() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Email2");
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange("A4:G11");
  var data=dataRange.getValues(); 
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var recipient = rowData[0];
    var emailAddress = rowData[1];
    var message1 = rowData[2];
    var parameter1 = rowData[3]
    var message2 = rowData[4];
    var message3 = rowData[5];
    var message4 = rowData[6]
    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ' ' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + ' ' + message3 + ' ' + message4 + ' ';
    var subject = 'Your deadline is this week';
    var Status=rowData[7];//I guessed because it's the only column left
    if (Status=="Not Started" || Status=="In Progress"){
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(i+4,11).setValue('Sent');

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Cooper
I just tried to run this and got the following error message for this line:

1) Error line: for (var =0;i<data.lengthi++) {
2) Error message: Missing variable name. (line 6, file "Email if cell blank")

I have encountered this line in  my googling, but am unsure as to how it functions, thus unable to rationalize how to troubleshoot this.